# used "mv (project directory) (whitespace)" and now my directory is gone

Tags: unix, mv

I accidentally did a `mv (project folder) (" ")` and now I can't find the folder. The folder is a flask project. I did a `ps -aux | grep flask` and the flask process is still running and functioning, but I can't find the project. I think I deleted it about 5 days ago or so, looking at my history. Is there any way i can recover it? I also tried looking for `....` everywhere and could not find it

edit: it appears to be deleted

`bash-4.1# lsof -p 34780 | grep cwd
flask   34780 root  cwd    DIR        8,6         0    9961663 /home/path... (deleted)`

Comment: `cd " "`? `mv " " myProjectFolder`?

Comment: @ext actually it looks like i did "mv (project folder) " with no whitespace. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your process is running in the folder try to find the PID with `ps ax | grep ...` and run `lsof -p $PID | grep cwd` which will show you the directory the process is running as:

```
my-process  12345  user  cwd    DIR  259,1     4096 16792359 /path/to/folder
```

This will show where it is but if it is just whitespace it might still be a bit hard to rename it. Notice the inode number before the path (`16792359` in this case). If you go to the parent folder you can rename it with:

```
find . -inum 16792359 -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' mv '{}' myNewProjectFolder
```

`-print0` and `xargs -0` helps with dealing with special characters such as spaces.

Comment: flask   34780 root  cwd    DIR        8,6         0    9961663 /home/path... (deleted)

Comment: how should I deal with it if it says (deleted) at the end of the path?

Comment: Then the directory has been deleted and you should start looking at recovery options. Try `ls -l /proc//proc/34780/fd/` and see if the directory entry is open (or perhaps some of your files), in that case use `ln /proc/34780/fd/$fd /path/to/new/filename`. Perhaps questions such as [unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files) will help you. `debugfs` is useful and since you have the directory inode chance of recovery is high.

Answer (score 0):

It's probable you moved your file to have a name of whitespace characters. So:

1. Try `ls -b` which should translate nonprinting characters to escapes.
2. Try `find . -name '* *'` which will look recursively for names with blanks.